# What is a good way to cook Turkey Chops?

Tags: meat, cast-iron, turkey, cutting

How should turkey chops be cooked so they are tasty? Is a cast iron pan needed or benefitial?

Comment: I don't think there is a well known cut called a "turkey chop."  Can you provide a photo or description of exactly what the chop you have is?

Comment: That link is going to a subscription page or something personalized to you.

Comment: Sorry, right link here: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51t3lGa-FXL.jpg

Comment: @samyb8 That doesn't look like turkey.

Comment: Well, Amazon sells it like Turkey Chops: http://www.amazon.com/Kosher-com-Glatt-Kosher-Turkey-Chops/dp/B004BHN2G2

Comment: @derobert, they look like cross-sections of large turkey legs, with that center bone being the femur.

Answer (score 4):

These are sections of turkey leg (drumstick) cut as to appear like a non-halal/kosher bone-in cut of meat, like a pork chop. The flesh is turkey, and hence not as robust as pork - treat more like a veal or lamb chop in terms of cooking technique, but season like pork or poultry. [Here is a thread on Chowhound](http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/922737) discussing various ways to prepare and serve.